# How do you handle a non-compiling code-state in a commit?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

I'm currently migrating a larger project (a game) to a different game-engine. Many things need to be adjusted, but most of the code itself can be kept as it is.

The migration includes multiple different steps like extending different base-classes or replacing method-calls with the ones form the new engine. Things, that I would normally put into multiple commits.

I know that it's bad practice to commit something, that will not compile into the VCS (because you create a point you can't safely return to later, since it is broken), but I also want to keep all those "migrating steps" separated (and not make *one* very huge commit, containing everything).

How would you handle this situation?

Comment: @zebediah49 the idea sounds right. Would you keep the separated branch or remove it after merging the changes into main?

Comment: E: tried what I suggested, and it didn't work quite right, so revision:  I would do all of that in a branch, then merge it back into master.  This will end up incorporating it into the history, but that should be OK?  Alternatively, you could keep the branch, but squash it in the master version to be a single monster-commit (with the note "see branch foo for more detail)  This will make sure that, say, git bisect won't put you on a commit that doesn't compile.